# Import pdf files to google play book application

Tags: pdf, google-play-books

I want to import my own PDF files to google play book reader and read them using this application. But without any hacking I cannot read not purchased PDFs in google playbook.

I'm not looking for an alternative because they are not good enough (such as ezPDF or Moon+ and ...)

Comment: @eldarerathis What/where is the duplicate question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## **You can import/upload them:**

### Uploading the PDF/ePub file(s) to your Library

1. Go to [My Books](https://play.google.com/books)
2. Click on 'Upload File' in the top right corner.
3. Choose the file(s) you wish to upload.

### Getting the PDF/ePub files in you App

1. Go into your [Google Play Books App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.books&hl=en).
2. Click on the button on the top left ('Read Now' or 'My Library').
3. Select 'My Library'.
4. Click on the button just underneath it ('All books').
5. Click on 'Uploads'.
6. Click the Android Menu button.
7. Click on 'Refresh'
8. When you try to open the file, you may be prompted to download it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid this is impossible. It's the number one most requested feature but, as far as I can tell, there are no plans to implement it. I suspect this is because Google is under quite a lot of fire for enabling piracy. Allowing people to load their own books into the books app would intensify that.